# Should we use assert in @BeforeClass or @BeforeTest annotations in TestNG, is it a good practice to do that?

Tags: selenium, testng

This is a sample code which will login into system

```
@BeforeClass
public void verifyLogin()
    {
    loginObject.enterUsername("admin");
    loginObject.enterPassword("!212313132");
    loginObject.clickOnsignIn();
    Assert.assertTrue(homeObject.isLoggedIn());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's more about opinion.

You are doing **login** in `@BeforeClass` , it must be validated which you are doing correctly by doing `Assert.assertTrue(homeObject.isLoggedIn());` this.

Because if login fails you might not wanna continue your testing.

Please note that `@BeforeTest` is bigger unit in **TestNG** as compared to `@BeforeClass`.

Personally I write login method in `@BeforeMethod` followed by all `@Test` methods in a class.

`@BeforeClass` is a **setupClass** in which you might want to declare your prerequisite such as driver initialization and all.

So coming to your question , where we should **assert** and what is **good practice**.

Wherever validation is required we must **assert**. It is as simple as that.

Comment: @DeepanshuRawat : Please let us know the status that it helped you or not ?

Answer (score 0):

Common design pattern for Selenium is the [Give-When-Then design](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Given-When-Then).

Looks like your described test contains the 'Given user X is logged in' therefore 'When..' and 'Then..'. So as the logged in user is a precondition in your test, it makes a lot of sense to assert it.

However, it's not mandatory. You can make 'homeObject.isLoggedIn()' method to throw LoginException in case of not finding a WebElement in the logged in page. In this way you would be capable to create a negative test (wrong password for example) which would use exactly the same code and would expect LoginException.